# Placing vue components into a separate file?

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Since I will be creating quite a lot of Vue components I want to put my Vue components into a separate file. This file would like something like this:

```
components.js

import Slide from './components/slider/Slide.vue';
import Slider from './components/slider/Slider.vue';

export default {
    Slide,
    Slider
};
```

Trying to import it into my Vue instance like so will not work:

```
import components from './components';

components: {
    components
},
```

How can I import these components into my Vue instance without having to explicitly define them? By defining them I mean doing something like this inside my components object:

`Slider: components.Slider`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spread components, like:

```
components: {
    ...components
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Just had to enable the stage-2 preset for babel to get this working. Thanks.